# Rounding a decimal number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I round a decimal number like `26,548746540516` to `26,5487` in MATLAB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`round`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) as follows

```
round(x*10000) / 10000.0
```

Alternatively, you can use [`round2`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4261-round2)

```
round2(x,0.0001)
round2(x,1e-4)
```

Comment: Note that round2 is not a builtin function (yet?).

Answer (score 2):

If it's purely display, you could also try sprintf() with formatted output. The syntax for what you want would be `sprintf('%.4f',26.548746540516);` You can see where you would need to change the number to a variable, and can easily change how many numbers after the decimal show up(before as well using %2.4f, for example).

Comment: No it is not purely display , i want to save it in the variable just with 4 digit after comma...

Comment: Put a str2double() around it and it's another solution